# Expect to scp directory does not work when run from post commit

Tags: scp, expect

I am trying to implement a post-commit hook on svn which will scp some files from the svn machine to some other backup machine after each commit.
I have written the script with expect as follows

```
spawn /usr/bin/scp -r $l_dir $r_usr@$r_host:/$r_dir

expect {
        timeout { send_user "Timeout"; exit 1 }

        eof { send_user "\nConnect failed for $r_host at \n"; exit 1 }

        -re ".*es..o.*" {
        send_user "sending yes\n"
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
        }
        -re ".*sword.*" {
        send_user "sending password\n"
        exp_send "$r_pwd\r"
        }
}
interact
```

This script is called from the post-commit (bash script) with all the required variables supplied.

The issue is that the when I execute the post-commit hook as

```
./post-commit
```

then the scp is succesful. but when it is triggered from an actual commit then the login andn supplying password is successful but the files are not copied

The script with debug output shows (when runnig from the commit trigger)

```
sending password
send: sending "vashishth\r" to { exp3 }
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0
```

Using RSA keys is not possible so I have to use the scp with password.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're saying `scp` can't use keys, it actually can - but I wasn't sure from your question if you thought that was possible or not.

Comment: I meant that sharing the keys is not allowed for the current svn and backup machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured out with some google
such cases running the expect from cron etc does not wok with interact
So I replaced the

```
interact
```

with

```
expect eof
exit
```

and the scp is successful

Comment: Nice work answering your own question! +1